# Create ListView/ListModel from a vector of strings

Tags: qt, qml

### Prologue

[QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) might be a solution, but I think it is a bit overkill for me ... not sure

### Intro

I'm making a vector inside C++ to be accessible from within QML:

```cpp
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<QString> items READ items WRITE setItems NOTIFY itemsChanged)
    // ...
}
```

As I have tested, I can access my vector from within QML:

```
console.log("myClass.items >>> ", myClass.items) // Logs vector of strings
```

---

### Question

On my QML UI, I intend to show a list of the strings inside the vector. I try to use `ListModel` and `ListView` but I don't know how to do it. Can anybody help?

```
    ListModel {
        id: myListModel
        // How to compose my model here according to vector of strings
        // i.e. myClass.items
    }

    ListView {
        model: myListModel
        delegate: {
            // ... show the strings inside the vector
        }
    }
```

---

### UPDATE

As suggested by @Amfasis and @mohabouje, I modified my code like this, but it is **not** working for some reason.

C++ side:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList items READ items WRITE setItems NOTIFY itemsChanged)
    //...
}
```

QML side:

```
            Row {
                ListView {
                    id: items
                    model: myClass.items // Directly connect to C++ string list
                    delegate: Text {
                        text: modelData // Strings are NOT displayed on QML UI
                                        // Log of modelData shows it is empty
                    }
                }
            }
```

On QML I log `myClass.items` and I see my string list:

```
console.log("myClass.items >>> ", myClass.items)
// logs:
// qml: myClass.items >>>  [item 0,item 1,item 2]
```

### Finally Fixed

When setting or modifying items, I need to `emit` the modification signal otherwise it won't work:

```
m_items = /* set items here */;
emit itemsChanged(m_items); // This is required!
```

Comment: You should use it without `ListModel`, bind your model directly to the vector: `model: myClass.items`

Comment: @Amfasis I did so, but for some reason it is not showing the string list on UI: ```ListView {
                    model: myClass.items
                    delegate: Text {
                        text: model.modelData
                    }
                }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expose your class interface to the QML engine. In this case, you can replace your `QVector<QString>` by an `QStringList`.

```
class MyModel: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList model READ model NOTIFY modelChanged)
    ...
};
```

If you take a look into the [docs](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models):

> Models that do not have named roles (such as the ListModel shown below) will have the data provided via the modelData role. The modelData role is also provided for models that have only one role. In this case the modelData role contains the same data as the named role.

So, you should use the property `modelData`:

```
ListView {
  model: mymodel.model
  delegate: Text {
     text: modelData
  }
}
```

To expose your C++ class, take a look into this [page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html).

Comment: Thanks! Let me try your solution ☺

Comment: I replaced `QVector<QString>` with `QStringList` and implemented `ListView {
                    model: myClass.items
                    delegate: Text {
                        text: modelData
                    }
                }` but it is not showing the stings. Not sure why ...

Comment: @user3405291 I just reproduced this and got my strings on screen... did you forget `anchors.fill: parent` or do you use a Layout? What's the version of Qt you are using?

Comment: @Amfasis I used `anchors.fill:parent` inside my `delegate: Text { ... }` but it didn't help. I use `anchors`, not `Layout`. I'm using Qt 5.12.2 on openSUSE Leap 15. The problem is when I log on console the `model` or `modelData` or `model.modelData`, they are all empty. But when I log `myClass.items`, it logs the strings on console.

Comment: @user3405291 did you change how the `myClass` gets into qml? You should get the whole list by logging `myModel.model` from this example, the `modelData` property is only available within the delegate

Comment: @Amfasis My naming is a bit different from this example. My Q_PROPERTY is named `items` and my class is named `MyClass` which is registered to be used inside QML. I can get the whole list by logging `myClass.items` from within QML ... which is equivalent to logging `myModel.model` on this example ... but the problem is when I set the ListView model to `model: myClass.items`, then the modelData inside my delegate is empty! I'm not sure why :(

Comment: @user3405291 ok, sounds fine... please try to make an isolated example, maybe check typos?

Comment: @Amfasis Thanks! If you can post your reproduced code, it might help me debug my code too ... Just if you like :)

Comment: @user3405291 I created a gist with my code for you to review: https://gist.github.com/amfasis/6db36254d204d33670f5dfb274dc139c

Comment: @Amfasis Thanks! That's great ☺ I'm going to debug my code according to the gist ☺

Comment: @Amfasis Finally I figured out why my code wasn't working =) I updated my post!